# compute joint probability of two variables with out using copulas

Tags: rainfall, statistics, storms, flooding

I have two timeseries one for a daily rainfall and another one for a daily storm surge height. I would like to calculate the probability of a certain rainfall depth with a certain storm surge height. Meaning the joint probability of rainfall 'x' happening with 'y' storm surge height. I understand there is an advanced way of computing that with copulas but is there a simpler way of computing that?